# How to upgrade python version in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I want to upgrade from python 2.7 to python 3.X in odoo, how can I upgrade. Is it possible using odoo console or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry to inform you but version 3.X is not yet compatible for odoo.

> if Python is already installed, make sure it is 2.7.9, previous
>   versions are less convenient and 3.x versions are not compatible with
>   Odoo

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html

Comment: Actually I want to use `tkinter` but I'm getting error while importing, I tried both `import tkinter` (python 2.7) and `import Tkinter` (python 3.x).

Comment: 3.x version having a lots more syntex and sematics changes with newer version so that 2.7.x is the stable choice for odoo

Comment: @Mohd.Merajuddinshaikh actually tkinter is deprecated in after OpenERP 6.1.X version so forget to check with tkinter with OpenERP becuase its completely remove and new version was came with web addons in OpenERP 7.0.X and later version